# How to create a branch from a GIT tag on gerrit server

Tags: git, git-branch, gerrit

I am trying to create a branch from a tag, which i created to save my work. I want to create that branch name on the gerrit server.

Can i use this commit id as SHA-1 and create a branch on the gerrit ? Is this the right way to create a branch ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct way. Nothing much else to say about it.